# Run Linux commands from Qt4

Tags: c++, linux, shell, qt4, posix

How can I run command-line programs under Linux from Qt4? And of course I want to obtain the output in some way I can use. I'd use it for an `ls | grep`, but it's good to know for any future issues.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Except when you're talking about one of its bindings (yes, I've seen that happen), but I'll let it slide.

Comment: If you don't want to block your app while QProcess runs look at the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098980/real-time-display-of-qprocess-output-in-a-textbrowser

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
QProcess p;
p.start( /* whatever your command is, see the doc for param types */ );
p.waitForFinished(-1);

QString p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();
QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [QProcess](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprocess.html).

Comment: For some tasks, it might be easier (or more robust) to roll your own code - you mention ls | grep, potentially QDir with a filter or a QRegExp might do what you need. For the general case, though, QProcess is absolutely the best way to go.

Comment: That's a great observation. I think I'll try that another time but the question in this case was also somewhat oriented for the general case for future uses.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What about using [popen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/popen.html)?

Comment: e8johan: True...I understand you want to use QT API but thought I'd give this answer. :)