# How to get STDOUT from a QProcess?

Tags: qt, process, stdout, qprocess

I thought I was going to get the output from a QProcess using the following code:

```
// Start the process
process.start(tr("php-cgi www/test.php"),QIODevice::ReadWrite);

// Wait for it to start
if(!process.waitForStarted())
    return 0;

// Continue reading the data until EOF reached
QByteArray data;

while(process.waitForReadyRead())
    data.append(process.readAll());

// Output the data
qDebug(data.data());
qDebug("Done!");
```

What I am expecting is to see the output from the program printed to the debug console, but all I see is:

> Done!

I know that:

- The program is started fine, because the message at the end is printed.
- The program *does* print output because running the exact same command in the terminal produces a long string of text as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148185/run-linux-command-line-commands-from-qt4/2148360#2148360

Comment: Solution in this question also makes sense, but it doesn't keep order of messages

Comment: There is no point enclosing executable with language translation macro tr(). I also doubt, that putting executable and parameter as first argument would work. Better: process.start("php-cgi", QStringList()<<"www/test.php",QIODevice::ReadWrite);

Comment: If you don't want to block your app while QProcess runs look at the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098980/real-time-display-of-qprocess-output-in-a-textbrowser

Comment: QProcess is Nice. Qt is ridiculously beautiful!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Before starting your process call:

```
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
```

It will cause printing everything (even STDERR output) to STDOUT output.

Answer (score 12):

Here is some clarification:

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum,

- `QProcess::MergedChannels`: `QProcess` merges the output of the running process into the standard output channel (stdout). **The standard error** channel (stderr) **will not** receive any data.[...]

*but*

- `QProcess::ForwardedChannels`: `QProcess` forwards the output of the running process onto the main process. **Anything** the child process writes to its standard output and standard error **will be written to the standard output and standard error** of the main process.

Comment: Processing the main process's output is slightly easier. So, thanks.