# Will QProcess::startDetached() cause a memory leak?

Tags: qt, qprocess

If i start a program with QProcess::startDetached() , and it will continue to execute after the parent process quits , so will this cause a memory leak ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get STDOUT from a QProcess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852587/how-to-get-stdout-from-a-qprocess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a static method. You're not even allocating anything. No leak.