# Cross-platform way to start a process and redirect its stdio

Tags: c++, stdio

I would like to know if there is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, BSD) library with which I could start a process asynchronously and have `iostream`-like wrappers for its standard pipes.

I would like it to be able to be able to tell when the process has terminated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 libraries you can use:

**QProcess**

You can use QProcess class from Qt toolkit.
More information can be found on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852587/how-to-get-stdout-from-a-qprocess) and [qt library](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html).

**libexecstream**

This [library](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/) is lighter than Qt, and is cross-platform

**Others**

- pstreams release 0.17

  > If you only want a console application you can use the old popen-based branch (release 0.17), which uses the Win32 functions _popen() and _pclose(), but these will not work in a GUI program (and might blow up your PC, if Windows doesn't do it for you.) This version doesn't have most of the library's features and is no longer maintained or tested.

Comment: Thank you for asuggestion, but since I don't already use Qt in my project, I would like something more lightweight.

Comment: did you use `system`? I think it's cross-platform.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using `system()`, but this is a blocking call and AFAIK does not enable input/output redirection.

Comment: Looks great but if I understand correctly, these are all POSIX-specific. I want it to work on Win32 (without Cygwin) as well.

Comment: pstreams FAQ notes that you can use [libexecstream](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/) which is cross-platform.

Comment: @Tibor Maybe you can [teach Windows Posix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746043/where-does-microsoft-windows-7-posix-implementation-currently-stand).

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that there **isn't** a lightweight library that does that **cross-platform**. So I decided to create a library since I need the functionality anyway.

Here's the library
https://github.com/Neko-Box-Coder/System2

It works for **posix** and **windows** systems. (It doesn't use popen for windows so it should also work in GUI applications)

It can send **input** and receive **output** from command.

And have **blocking** and **non-blocking** version.

And it has both **header only** and source version as well