# Executing a .bat file with a parameter and reading the console output in C++

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, shellexecute

I have a batch file I need to execute, it has one parameter, If I were to run this script myself I would open up cmd and write

```
lexparser.bat texfile.txt
```

and the output would then be printed to the console.
I have shopped around and I have found some code which seems to be executing the file but I can't seem to extract the data being output, but I am unsure if this is correct.

```
QString pathDocument = qApp->applicationDirPath()+ "/stanford/lexparser.bat";
long result = (long)ShellExecute(0, 0, reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR*>(pathDocument.utf16()), 0, 0, SW_NORMAL);
```

I am using C++ as my language and I am also using the Qt Library to help me.
I have limited programming ability so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `QProcess` for doing that.

See [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852587/how-to-get-stdout-from-a-qprocess) for an example on how to do so.