# Display wget console output in Gui

Tags: c++, qt-creator, wget

I am trying to create a simple GUI application in QT Creator that uses `wget` to download files from websites. I want to be able to see the `wget` output in the GUI.

I want this output:

```
--2014-04-27 13:58:58--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 74.125.224.192, 74.125.224.193, 74.125.224.206, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|74.125.224.192|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2014-04-27 13:58:58--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 74.125.224.210, 74.125.224.209, 74.125.224.208, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|74.125.224.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>                                   ] 11,802      --.-K/s   in 0.005s  

2014-04-27 13:58:58 (2.16 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [11802]
```

This is what I have so far. It downloads the file, but I don't see any output in the text browser. I am piping the QProcess output to the text browser. Commands like `ls` do display output.

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;




MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = new QProcess(this);
    //connect (process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(printOutput()));

}



MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("Pressed!");



}
void MainWindow::printOutput()
{
    ui->display->setPlainText(process->readAllStandardOutput());
}


void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{    connect (process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(printOutput()));


    string result = "wget ";
    result += ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();

    ui->label->setText("Fetching...");
    QString lawl = QString::fromStdString(result);

    options.clear();
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    options << "-c" << lawl;
    process->start("/bin/sh", options);
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    process->start(ui->lineEdit->text(), options);
#endif
    process->waitForFinished();

}
```

With `process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);`

Output:

```
                                129K=0.09s

2014-04-27 19:11:14 (129 KB/s) - ‘index.html.3’ saved [11786]
```

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852587/how-to-get-stdout-from-a-qprocess

Comment: @1.618 Thanks!
It does provide output, but not exactly the whole thing. I updated the question with the output.

Comment: `wget` might change its output depending on if its output is a terminal or not. (It can detect this via C's `isatty` function or equivalent.) If that's the case, you have to do some "create a pseudo-TTY" trickery to get it to output what you want (I don't have the details handy; sorry).

Comment: Another thing you could do, since you're approaching this from a program angle, is to use `libcurl` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget draws a progress bar using escape sequences (probably using curses).  I'm guessing that this is preventing the QProcess object from capturing the output correctly.  It doesn't look like there's a way to disable just the progress bar without disabling the rest of the verbose output.

As a workaround, you could use the -o option to make wget log to a file.  When the process completes, read and display the file.