# Real time display of QProcess output in a textBrowser

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qprocess

I am a newbie in qt development and i want to transfer the output of QProcess to a textBrowser in real time. I started by executing a simple echo command,but the output of the program is not getting displayed.
What am i doing wrong????

```
QProcess p;
p.start("echo hye");
QByteArray byteArray = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    QStringList strLines = QString(byteArray).split("\n");
    QString line= p.readAllStandardOutput();
    if(p.state()==QProcess::NotRunning)
        ui->textBrowser->append("not running");
    foreach (QString line, strLines){
    ui->textBrowser->append(line);}
```

P.S. I am on a linux machine.

EDIT:
I am still not able to get the output in a textBrowser .

I changed the Qprocess parameters and tried both waitForStarted() and waitForReadyRead() so that the process starts in time and the results are available.

I added waitForFinished() so that the process does not terminate when it goes out of scope.

```
QProcess p;
    p.start("echo", QStringList() << "hye");
    p.waitForStarted();
    QByteArray byteArray = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    QStringList strLines = QString(byteArray).split("\n");
    QString line= p.readAllStandardOutput();
    if(p.state()==QProcess::NotRunning)
        ui->textBrowser->append("not running");
    ui->textBrowser->append(line);
    p.waitForFinished();
```

Answer (score 9):

to read standard output you need to either call `waitForReadyRead()` before reading stardard output , or you need to connect Qprocess's signal `readyReadStandardOutput()` to your slot and read standard output from slot.

also make sure that your QProcess is not on stack.

I tried following code works fine.

EDIT:

```
MyProcess::MyProcess(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QString program = "echo";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "Hello";
    mProcess.start(program,arguments);
    connect(&mProcess,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(readyReadStandardOutput()));
    connect(&mProcess,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(readyReadStandardError()));
}

void MyProcess::readyReadStandardOutput(){
    qDebug()<< mProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
}

void MyProcess::readyReadStandardError(){
    qDebug() << mProcess.readAllStandardError();
}
```

Comment: I would like to display the results in a textBrowser,but this code displays results in qt's terminal itself.

Comment: well, you can use ui->textBrowser->append instead of qDebug()

Comment: See https://sites.google.com/site/marcsturmspages/qt/qt-workaround-for-the-leaky-qprocess-output-channel for the buffering issue and its workaround.

Comment: Thanks for reminding on waitForReadyRead()! For my app it was sufficient and using this doesn't require to subclass from QProcess.