# Get output of Qprocess in a variable?

Tags: qt, stdout, qprocess

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2148185/1214214).
The difference is that the solution specified there doesn't work always.

**Example 1**

```
QProcess * process;
process = new QProcess();
process->start("/usr/bin/env");
process->waitForFinished(-1);

QString p_stdout = process->readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << p_stdout;

//output
HOME=/home
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DISPLAY=:0.0
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home
```

Everything works, and the output is like typing `/usr/sbin/env` in the terminal.

**Example 2**

```
QProcess * process;
process = new QProcess();
process->start("/usr/sbin/iptables");
process->waitForFinished(-1);

QString p_stdout = process->readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << p_stdout;

//output
""
```

Same code, just a different command and no output. There is output when i type `/usr/sbin/iptables` in the terminal

> iptables v1.4.16.3: no command specified
>   Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

bit it doesn't appear in `p_stdout`.
What is the catch with this solution?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the error signal in QProcess and reading from standard error?

Comment: Did you try `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` too?

Comment: @vahancho Yes, that was the problem. I've solved it with `process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);`

Comment: Alan, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question. Write your solution as an answer, and delete the comment. You should then also flag my comment and all the other comments as obsolete (since they will be, then!).